# Why is there only one hidden layer in a neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I recently made my first neural network simulation which also uses a genetic evolution algorithm. It's simple software that just simulates simple organisms collecting food, and they evolve, as one would expect, from organisms with random and sporadic movements into organisms with controlled, food-seeking movements. Since this kind of organism is so simple, I only used a few hidden layer neurons and a few input and output neurons. I understand that more complex neural networks could be made by simply adding more neurons, but can't you add more layers? Or would this create some kind of redundancy? All of the pictures of diagrams of neural networks, such as this one http://mechanicalforex.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/NN.png, always have one input layer, one hidden layer, and one output layer. Couldn't a more complex neural network be made if you just added a bunch of hidden layers? Of course this would make processing the neural network harder, but would it create any sort of advantage, or would it be just the same as adding more neurons to a single layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include as many hidden layers you want, starting from zero (--that case is called *perceptron*).

The ability to represent unknown functions, however, does -- in principle -- not increase. Single-hidden layer neural networks already possess a [*universal representation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) property: by increasing the number of hidden neurons, they can fit (almost) arbitrary functions. You can't get more than this. And particularly not by adding more layers.

However, that doesn't mean that multi-hidden-layer ANN's can't be useful *in practice*. Yet, as you get another dimension in your parameter set, people usually stuck with the single-hidden-layer version.

Comment: Oh I see, I sort of suspected something like this but I had no idea how to prove it. Also, does the way the weighted values are dealt with matter? What I mean is, if you take weighted values and average them into a neuron or multiply them into a neuron does it make a difference? Will the genetic algorithm perfect the weights in either case? Or is there some mathematically better way to deal with values in a neural network than averaging or multiplying?

Comment: @SullyChen: sure you can abstract on the aggregation function, it doesn't have to be "sum-of-products". But again, it doesn't give you a free lunch. There might be problems which will work better with another aggregation, but others might not. To stress it: the ANN has in principle everything that it needs to fit arbitrary functions. You can vary the approach at each corner, but you won't get better *in theory* (maybe in practice, but this must be analyzed case-by-case).

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm very new to learning algorithms. Thank you for the information!

Comment: It should be noted that the universal representation property applies to representing *continuous functions*, which is usually not the goal when applying a neural network. Having a second hidden layer can provide significant improvement for many problems.